# Android CoordinatorLayout align 3 views having the middle view fill the space

Tags: android, vertical-alignment, android-coordinatorlayout

This may be a simple question, but can't manage to find a simple answer:

*Is there any way to have in a `CoordinatorLayout` 3 vertically aligned views so that the view in the middle expands itself to fill all the space?*

I'm looking for something similar to `below` and `above` behaviour in `RelativeLayout`, or a LinearLayout with a `layout_weight=1` for the middle view.

Comment: You only want to use the coordinator layout?

Comment: @KaranMehta yep, unfortunately this is a maintenance project which heavily depends on CoordinatorLayout in a screen I need to make little tweaks